# how to redirect a child process's output to syslog?

Tags: c, syslog

I'm developing in C under freebsd. I'm using cron job to invoke a program A which uses fork()/exec() to call another program B. In A, I use syslog() to write logs to /var/log/messages, but B outputs to stdout so B's output is not written to /var/log/messages.

How can I redirect B's output to syslog also without modifying B's code? I guess there should be some mechanism to redirect B's output to some fd in A, but since I'm using syslog() instead of opening a file directly in A, I'm not sure how this would work.

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Look into `popen`, which allows you access to the process's input and output file descriptors, and perhaps you can use that in lieu ofy our own fork/exec.

Answer (score 1):

I can't recall if freebsd includes the logger program. If so, your program A might be able to invoke B as some form of "B | logger". For example, instead of

```
execl("/my/path/to/B", "B", NULL);
```

Leverage the shell:

```
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "/my/path/to/B | logger", NULL);
```

The *logger* program has additional options to direct its messages to a particular syslog facility, which may be needed to match your A application's behavior.

Lacking *logger*, you may need to do traditional Posix pipe-fitting: use *pipe(2)* to create a pipe, dup the output side of the pipe to B's stdout, and read (either in A, or in a separate child process) that pipe's input side for messages to send to *syslog(3)*

Comment: Thanks Sjnarv. I found logger in my bsd system. But, can I still get the return code of B? I think the return code of "B | logger" will be the return code of 'logger', no matter what B returns.

Comment: Also, what's the difference between "cmd" and "sh -c cmd"?

Comment: First question: I think you are right, in that you will not get the status of the first command in the pipeline. As an alternative, perhaps invocation of 'B' needs instead to be an invocation of a script named, say, B_wrapper.sh, a bash script that invokes the 'B | logger' pipeline, and uses the bash array PIPESTATUS to return exit status from the first command.

For your second question: no practical difference I'm aware of, if "cmd" is an executable command (ie, file name). I was using a "cmd" that includes shell-specific syntax (eg, "cmd1 | cmd2"), so the shell could do the pipe-fitting.

Comment: There is a utility named `logwrapper` that redirects STDOUT/STDERR of an executable (provided as an argument) to Android's logging system. I haven't been able to find a similar satisfactory tool for Linux. `logger` can only be used in a shell script.